# LettuceEncrypt - Kestrel Behind a TCP Load Balancer (aka SSL pass-thru)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt, kestrel

I have no experience with Nginx. I tried to configure Nginx however, I have still bad results. Is here someone who can help me with the configuration for "Kestrel Behind a TCP Load Balancer (aka SSL pass-thru)"?

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem:

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
            wb1.com             wb1;
            wb2.com             wb2;
            default             wb1;
     }
    upstream wb1 {
        server              127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
    upstream wb2 {
        server              127.0.0.1:5001;
    }
    server {
        listen              443;
        proxy_pass          $name;
        ssl_preread             on; 
    }
}
```

If you have some experience and can you advise me better solution, please create an answer.